# What design patten it is that the class variable has the class itself

Tags: swift, design-patterns

A class variable that contains the class itself, for example, the [main](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/1781006-main) property of the class [DispatchQueue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue)

**Question 1**

What kind of design pattern it is? Is this related to Singleton?

**Question 2**

How does the object initialized when referring this property?

Comment: There's nothing special about it, it's just a share object instance.

Comment: What is shared object instance? shared by who?

Comment: An object is an instance of a class. Objects are references by variables. A single object can be referenced to by multiple variables. The people who wrote `DispatchQueue` put in a static variable that references an instance of `DispatchQueue`, and made it public for others to use. Any time you run `DispatchQueue.main`, you're getting a reference to that shared object. There's nothing special about it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is the singleton pattern. It is all over swift like `UserDefaults.standard`, `NotificationCenter.default`, `FileManager.default`, ... For instance, `URLSession.shared` is defined in the apple [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1409000-shared) as:

> The shared singleton session object.

The singleton pattern makes sure that only one instance of the class is created. The class lazily creates its sole instance the first time it is requested and thereafter ensures that no other instance can be created.

Here is some sample code:

```
class MyClass {
    static let shared = MyClass()

    //Make the initializer private
    private init(){}

    //Here is a sample method
    func doSomething() {
        print("Doing something")
    }
}
```

Making the initializer prevents the possibility of creating many instances, and thus the following line would yield an error:

```
let instance = MyClass() //MyClass initializer is inaccessible due to private protection level
```

To access the singleton use `MyClass.shared`:

```
let instance = MyClass.shared
instance.doSomething() //Prints: Doing something
```

For more details on the singleton pattern in Swift, you may look [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cocoa_design_patterns/managing_a_shared_resource_using_a_singleton) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Singleton.html).

Comment: None of those are singletons. All of those classes have public initializes, that allow you to create your own instances, if desired. There's nothing "single" about them.

Comment: @Alexander you're wrong since you could declare this `let sharedURLSession = URLSession.shared` and the same for the examples given above.

Comment: It depends on how strictly you're interpreting "singleton pattern"  It can be argued that the pattern itself requires that there only be one instance in which case the things mentioned are *not* singletons, as it is possible to create other instances.

Comment: @Carpsen90 What's your point? You could also do `let aNewURLSession = URLSession(configuration: someURLSessionConfiguration)`, and all of a sudden, there's more than a single instance of `URLSession`. Thus, `URLSession` isn't following a singleton pattern, and its `shared` property isn't a singleton. It's just one object, but there could be others

Comment: @Alexander please refer to the Apple docs, it is defined as: The shared singleton session object https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1409000-shared

Comment: @Carpsen90 They're wrong, technically speaking. [Singleton Pattern on Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) the singleton pattern is a software design pattern ***that restricts the instantiation of a class to one object.***

Comment: I believe this question is tagged `swift` and `iOS` and not a wikipedia link that anybody can edit. Here is how Apple defines a singleton: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Singleton.html